# Can someone turn this array code into a non-array method to achieve the same results?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I have here a piece of code that record the number of bottles collected by 4 rooms. When the user types in quit, the program spits out the number of bottles collect by each room and determines the room with the highest number of bottles collected. I have used an array method, but to I shouldn't use this method, just to show how useful array are. Can anyone give me any pointers?

```
namespace BottleDrive
  {
      class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {//Initialize array of rooms to 4
            int[] rooms = new int[4];
            //Start of while loop to ask what room your adding into. 
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the room you're in: ");
                //If user enters quit at anytime, the code will jump out of while statement and enter for loop below
                string quit = Console.ReadLine();
                if (quit == "quit")
                    //Break statement allows quit to jump out of loop
                    break; 
               //Variable room holds the number of bottles collect by each room. 
                int room = int.Parse(quit);
                Console.Write("Bottles collected in room {0}: ", room);
                // This line adds the count of bottles and records it so you can continuously count the bottles collected.
                rooms[room - 1] += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                
            }
            //This for statement lists the 4 rooms and their bottle count when the user has entered quit. An alternative to below
            /*for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; ++i)
                Console.WriteLine("Bottles collected in room {0} = {1}", i + 1, rooms[i]);*/

            int maxValue = 0;//initiates the winner, contructor starts at 0
            int maxRoomNumber = 0;//initiates the room number that wins
            for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; ++i)//This loop goes through the array of rooms (4)
            {
                if (rooms[i] > maxValue)//Makes sure that the maxValue is picked in the array
                {//Looking for room number for the 
                    maxValue = rooms[i];
                    maxRoomNumber = i + 1;
                }//Writes the bottles collected by the different rooms
                Console.WriteLine("Bottles collected in room {0} = {1}", i + 1, rooms[i]);
            }
            //Outputs winner
            Console.WriteLine("And the Winner is room " + maxRoomNumber + "!!!");

        }
          }
            }
```

Comment: You could use `List<int>` and LINQ to show how useless arrays are...

Comment: LINQ is something my class haven't touched on. Is there anymore primitive way than LINQ?

Comment: Insert obligatory pointers joke... "here's a few... 0x013d2da0 and 0x4e326dbb"

Comment: @Marc - about time you upgraded to 64 bit, don't you think? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that uses a Class to hold the information for each room. The reason for using a class is so that if your program needs to change in the future to collect more information, you won't have to track yet another array, you can just add properties to the class.

The individual rooms are now held in a list instead of an array just to show a different construct.

Here is the new Room class:

```
public class Room
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int BottleCount { get; set; }

    public Room(int wNumber)
    {
        Number = wNumber;
    }
}
```

And here is the new version of the program. Note that additional checking of the values entered by the end user has been added in order to prevent exceptions when trying to get the current room or parse to an int the value entered by the user:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int MAX_ROOMS = 4;
        var cRooms = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Room>();

        for (int nI = 0; nI < MAX_ROOMS; nI++)
        {
            // The room number is 1 to 4
            cRooms.Add(new Room(nI + 1));
        }

        // Initializes the room that wins
        //Start of while loop to ask what room your adding into. 
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the room you're in: ");
            //If user enters quit at anytime, the code will jump out of while statement and enter for loop below
            string roomNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            if (roomNumber == "quit")
            {
                //Break statement allows quit to jump out of loop
                break;
            }
            int room = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(roomNumber, out room) && (room < MAX_ROOMS) && (room >= 0)) {
                Room currentRoom;

                currentRoom = cRooms[room];

                Console.Write("Bottles collected in room {0}: ", currentRoom.Number);

                int wBottleCount = 0;

                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out wBottleCount) && (wBottleCount >= 0))
                {
                    // This line adds the count of bottles and records it so you can continuously count the bottles collected.
                    currentRoom.BottleCount += wBottleCount;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid bottle count; value must be greater than 0");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid room number; value must be between 1 and " + MAX_ROOMS.ToString());
            }
        }

        Room maxRoom = null;

        foreach (Room currentRoom in cRooms) //This loop goes through the array of rooms (4)
        {
            // This assumes that the bottle count can never be decreased in a room
            if ((maxRoom == null) || (maxRoom.BottleCount < currentRoom.BottleCount))
            {
                maxRoom = currentRoom;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Bottles collected in room {0} = {1}", currentRoom.Number, currentRoom.BottleCount);
        }
        //Outputs winner
        Console.WriteLine("And the Winner is room " + maxRoom.Number + "!!!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed to use arrays, you can declare 4 variables for all your array items.

```
int room1, room2, room3, room4;
```

I guess that's the intended approach to this exercise.

Comment: If i int room1, room2, room3, room4, how can i use the array call line to make it fit into my intiated room number? 

               Console.Write("Bottles collected in room {0}: ", room);
                // This line adds the count of bottles and records it so you can continuously count the bottles collected.
                rooms[room - 1] += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());     

Because i call through array, how can i call the individual initated room?

Comment: This would be `room1 = int.Parse( ... ); room2 = int.Parse( ... )`, etc;